# Set PyCharm Virrtualenv on WSL

Tags: pycharm, virtualenv, local, pyenv

I created a django project on my WSL Ubuntu (20.04.1) and before I run this command to create a virtualenv:

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.6.6 my_site
pyenv local my_site
```

After I opened the project on PyCharm (2020.3.3 Professional Edition) I tried to set the existing virtualenv:

[image]

I am confused wether to use Virtualenv Environment (and check existing environment) or WSL.

Anyway I can't figure out which path I should include. Any suggestion?